# A reportviewer control bug to display unicode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, reportviewer

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + IIS 7.0 with reportviewer control. The report created by reportviewer control is very simple, just a single line of Chinese characters (I wrote the line of characters statically in a textbox control, no additional dynamically generating or fetching from database).

I upload the error PDF file exported by the report viewer and screen snapshot here, and my most confusion is why the exported PDF file is just 2k size? Is this issue caused by font not embedded in PDF file? Actually I did not find how to embed font in PDF file. Appreciate if anyone could give me some good ideas.

This is the error PDF displayed screen snapshot,

http://www.4shared.com/photo/gs_KvxSW/characterissue.html

This is the error PDF itself,

http://www.4shared.com/document/4Fs5rCH_/characterissue.html

Comment: What is the actual error?  I see chinese characters.

Comment: The character is not correct. I searched on the web, it seems it is reportviewer's bug which does not embed font to cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There were issues with rendering of Unicode characters into PDF using `ReportViewer` control, which are fixed in version 11 of the runtime. If upgrade is an option for you, give it a try.

See [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1c387f26-49ad-4f82-83d6-6422dcd7cd89/special-characters-displayed-incorrectly-when-compression-disabled-in-local-reportviewer?forum=vsreportcontrols) for more information.